# Translating a Latin parody of "Pange Lingua" about a critic of the new 10% tax newly instituted in 1710

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation

> Non ex mente Philipina
>   　haec venit taxatio:
>   Infernalis inimici
>   　Est vera inventio.
>   Occasus Regni Gallici,
>   　Et extrema unctio

I have attempted to translate the above:

> Not from the mind of Philippe [II]
>   　today comes the taxation:
>   The infernal enemy
>   　Is a mere device.
>   Sunset and last rites
>   　of the French kings.

Though it seems to make sense to me, any criticism of the translation, shades of meaning, word choice, etc., is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“This taxation does not spring from the mind of Philip. It is the true invention of the Infernal Enemy, the downfall of the Gallic kingdom and its Extreme Unction.”

Answer (score 4):

I fixed your Latin for you, assuming the [text I was using](https://satires18.univ-st-etienne.fr/texte/latin/sans-titre) is right. At the very least, *unction* and *taxation* are English, not Latin, words, but *mera inventio* is a possibility.

If it's *vera*, like the text I linked to says, than it would be "true device."

Some other random notes:

There is no word for "today" in the poem; *haec* means "this."

*Infernalis inimici* looks to me like it should be a genitive, though it's awkward (or just poetic).

While *occasus* can mean "sunset," I wonder if it actually means "downfall" here, as it so often seems to do. There's nothing indicating the "falling down" is related to the sun (cf. *occasum solis* in Caesar).